# Setting up a big commerce stencil environment

Tags: development-environment, bigcommerce

I am using a mac and have been following the instruction on how to set up a Big commerce stencil development environment posted here:

https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/prerequisites

When trying to launch stencil:

```
stencil start
```

in the template directory called "airflow" - see screenshot for the directory structure - I receive:

```
-bash: stencil: command not found
```

[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX8oh.png)

I have been trough the trouble shooting pages

and verified I have the correct versions of npm, node and nvm

npm -v
2.14.20
node -v
v4.4.0

I have also confirmed there is only one version of node installed:

```
ls ~/.nvm/versions/node
v4.4.0
```

Is there any advice anyone can give on how to troubleshoot this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you installed stencil-cli globally?  Run `npm ls -g --depth=0` and confirm that @bigcommerce/stencil-cli is listed.  If not, install it with the `-g` flag...ie: `npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli`

Second, make sure you're running the stencil commands in the directory that contains the `.stencil` file...in your screenshot that'd be the "stencil" directory inside of "airflow".

Hope this helps!